# Why is using Outlook to monitor Gmail accounts so slow?

Tags: email, gmail, microsoft-outlook-2007

I have a couple of gmail accounts monitored through IMAP by Outlook 2007. It works but is really slow to detect emails... emails coming into other accounts are alerted immediately but often it takes several minutes for Outlook to realise gmail emails have arrived - I can test by having gmail in a browser and comparing.

Also, folders that receive gmail emails frequently don't do the **myfolder(1)** thing... I'll get the envelope icon indicating an email has arrived, but have to manually look at each folder to check - as soon as I click the folder containing the new email it updates correctly.

Is this an Outlook problem? Or a gmail problem? Or an IMAP problem? Or a problem with how I've configured things?

Answer (score 1):

Check this out: http://www.labnol.org/software/tutorials/solutions-for-slow-gmail-imap-with-microsoft-outlook/1761/

Answer (score 0):

You need to tune the send/receive interval in outlook settings.